# Jquery Slide panel - Close original panel when next panel loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out a small issue I'm having with some jQuery.

Basically what I require is that when one panel is open, if the user clicks the trigger for the other panel, then the original panel will slide up and bring the new panel down in its place.

You can see what I've got so far over on [www.google-boost.co.uk](http://www.google-boost.co.uk), the two triggers will be the 2 most right icons on the nav menu.

### JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nx6v

My sample code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

        $(".btn-slide-two").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

    if (!panel.is(':visible')) {
        $('.panel').hide(opts.speed);$('.btn-slide').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be nice , if you just post the code of just the slidedown, creating a fiddle would do better.

Comment: simply .hide() on original element or am i missing the point

Comment: Hi Sarah, Thanks for the feedback. i've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nx6v/ :) thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That works, however it's instant, would there be any way to transition between the two? so that the original slide would slide up and the new slide down in it's place?

Comment: +1 for providing a JSFiddle to work with. Will add it to your question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal solution is to connect links and panels via data attributes. This way you only need one piece of code and share a single class amongst the links.

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4Nx6v/1/

Link are like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-slider" data-target="#panel">
```

Code then looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Apply to all buttons of class btn-slider
    $(".btn-slider").click(function () {
        // remove active from all active links and collapse them
        $('.btn-slider.active').each(function () {
            var $link = $(this);
            $($link.attr('data-target')).slideUp("slow");
            $link.removeClass("active");
        });
        // Add active to the clicked link and slidedown the matching content
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('data-target')).slideDown("slow");
        return false;
    });

    if (!panel.is(':visible')) {
        $('.panel').hide(opts.speed);
        $('.btn-slider').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

*This code can be fine-turned a bit more, but what do expect for 2 mins work :)*

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4Nx6v/3/

Based on the requirement to toggle, this is slightly better:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-slider").click(function () {
        var $clicked = $(this);
        $('.btn-slider.active').each(function () {
            var $link = $(this);
            // If this is not the clicked link, collapse its panel
            if (!$link.is($clicked)) {
                $($link.attr('data-target')).slideUp("slow");
                $link.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
        $clicked.toggleClass("active");
        if ($clicked.hasClass("active")) {
            $($clicked.attr('data-target')).slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $($clicked.attr('data-target')).slideUp("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

    if (!panel.is(':visible')) {
        $('.panel').hide(opts.speed);
        $('.btn-slider').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! Thanks alot mate! Only problem i'm having now is one panel is always displayed, i'd need them to be hidden when the user hits the trigger again so that they stay out of site above the footer? i really need to brush up on jquery! damn

Comment: @user2810948: Update above. Little bit long-winded, but basically skip collapsing the selected link on click and toggle that link's panel. probably better shortcuts to do this in JQuery. Will keep looking.

Comment: This is pretty damn sweet! cheers mate, now, just to be a bit pedantic  lol, i'm trying to experiment with the fadeIn/FadeOut/fadeTo effects of jquery, so that when one panel is loaded, if the other trigger is clicked the content of panel1 fades out and panel2 fades in, I'm having a couple of issues where i can get the panels to fade, but not slide down then fade between the content of the 2 panels.

tonight.. i think i'll be mostly burying my head in a whole load of jquery tutorials!

Comment: @user2810948: The problem you will face is that "slid fully up" = hidden and "faded fully out" also = hidden. You need to set the opacity to a small non-zero value for the slide to have something to work on (but still be invisible). Give yourself a real username on SO... I expect you will be back.

Comment: I guess that makes sense! cheers for all the help mate, i'll definitely be back, after i hit the books!